# No module names URLs on Django with mod_wsgi?

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run a Django project using Apache2 mod_wsgi on my Debian 6 machine. This project runs fine if I start this project with the development server. But now I get this error:

```
Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named urls
```

My project name is genalytics. There's only one app called fileupload. I have this available on my settings.py:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'genalytics.urls'
```

Here's the tree structure of my project:

```
 genalytics/
    ├── fileupload
    │   ├── backend.py
    │   ├── backend.pyc
    │   ├── backends.py
    │   ├── backends.pyc
    │   ├── django.wsgi
    │   ├── encrypt.py
    │   ├── encrypt.pyc
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── forms.pyc
    │   ├── functions.py
    │   ├── functions.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── middleware.py
    │   ├── middleware.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── models.pyc
    │   ├── static
    │   │   ├── admin
    │   │   │   ├── css
    │   │   │   │   ├── base.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── changelists.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── dashboard.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── forms.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── ie.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── login.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── rtl.css
    │   │   │   │   └── widgets.css
    │   │   │   ├── img
    │   │   │   │   ├── changelist-bg.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── changelist-bg_rtl.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── chooser-bg.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tool-right.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tool-right_over.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tooltag-add.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tooltag-add_over.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tooltag-arrowright.gif
    │   │   │   │   └── tooltag-arrowright_over.gif
    │   │   │   └── js
    │   │   │       ├── actions.js
    │   │   │       ├── actions.min.js
    │   │   │       ├── admin
    │   │   │       │   ├── DateTimeShortcuts.js
    │   │   │       │   ├── ordering.js
    │   │   │       │   └── RelatedObjectLookups.js
    │   │   │       ├── calendar.js
    │   │   │       ├── collapse.js
    │   │   │       └── urlify.js
    │   │   ├── css
    │   │   │   ├── datepicker.css
    │   │   │   ├── datePicker.css
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-ui.css~
    │   │   │   ├── pro_dropline.css
    │   │   │   ├── pro_dropline_ie.css
    │   │   │   ├── screen.css
    │   │   │   └── screen.css~
    │   │   ├── endless_pagination
    │   │   │   └── js
    │   │   │       ├── endless.js
    │   │   │       ├── endless_on_scroll.js
    │   │   │       └── endless-pagination.js
    │   │   │   ├── transfer.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
    │   │   │   ├── upload.png
    │   │   │   └── up.png
    │   │   ├── js
    │   │   │   ├── endless-pagination.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery
    │   │   │   │   ├── Copy of custom_jquery.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── custom_jquery.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── date.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery-1.4.1.min.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.bind.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.datePicker.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.dimensions.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.filestyle.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.pngFix.pack.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.selectbox-0.5.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_2.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_3.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.tablesorter.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.tooltip.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.usermode.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── ui.checkbox.js
    │   │   │   │   └── ui.core.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-1.9.1.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-latest.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery.pajinate.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery.tablesorter.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js
    │   │   │   ├── test.js~
    │   │   │   └── transfer.js
    │   │   ├── login.css
    │   │   ├── PIE.htc
    │   │   ├── style.css
    │   │   └── style.css~
    │   ├── svn-commit.tmp
    │   ├── tasks.py
    │   ├── tasks.py~
    │   ├── tasks.pyc
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   ├── ajax.html
    │   │   ├── base.html
    │   │   ├── create_session.html
    │   │   ├── create_session.html~
    │   │   ├── deleted_files.html
    │   │   ├── edit_session.html
    │   │   ├── file_info.html
    │   │   ├── footer.html
    │   │   ├── forgot_password.html
    │   │   ├── form.html
    │   │   ├── header.html
    │   │   ├── list_files.html
    │   │   ├── list_session.html
    │   │   ├── list_session.html~
    │   │   ├── login_backend.html
    │   │   ├── message_forgot.html
    │   │   ├── nav.html
    │   │   ├── new_password.html
    │   │   ├── notify.html
    │   │   ├── overview.html
    │   │   ├── overview.html~
    │   │   ├── password_successful.html
    │   │   ├── reform.html
    │   │   ├── registration
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_complete.html
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_confirm.html
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_done.html
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_email.html
    │   │   │   └── password_reset_form.html
    │   │   ├── right.html
    │   │   ├── search_result.html
    │   │   ├── shared_by_me.html
    │   │   ├── shared_with_me.html
    │   │   ├── style.css
    │   │   ├── synced.html
    │   │   ├── test.html
    │   │   ├── test.html~
    │   │   ├── thanks.html
    │   │   ├── uploaded_files.html
    │   │   ├── uploaded_files.html~
    │   │   └── uploaded_notify.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   ├── views.py~
    │   └── views.pyc
    ├── genalytics
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── settings.py~
    │   ├── settings.pyc
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   ├── wsgi.py~
    │   └── wsgi.pyc
    └── manage.py
```

Content of httpd.conf of Apache:

```
Listen 8000

<VirtualHost *:8000>
   ServerName NFS

   DocumentRoot /opt/genalytics


   WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/genalytics/genalytics/wsgi.py
   <Directory /opt/genalytics/genalytics>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   Alias /static /opt/genalytics/fileupload/static

</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py content:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/opt/genalytics')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "genalytics.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I am using Django 1.5. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using any virtual environment for your application.

Comment: have you check apache log ? and if you are using virtualenv then in wsgi file you need to append virtualenv path.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to say I am not using virtualenv.

Comment: Could you please show apache log.

Comment: Hi, I only have sudo access on my server. Apparently, the log of apache2 can't be opened by the sudo user. I need to be the root user.

Comment: mproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware fileupload.middleware: "No module named middleware"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change this line in your `wsgi.py`:

```
sys.path.append('/opt/genalytics')
```

to:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/genalytics')
```